# Compile JInput on ARM

Tags: linux, java

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, and an arduino pro micro set up as a Joystick. On the Pi i have a java application that runs well on a PC with both Linux and Windows with the arduino joystick connected. But as soon as I start running the program on the pi I get an error message like:

```
`Failed to load library:" /libjinput-linux64.so: /libjinput-linux64.so`
```

After some googling around i find that the problem is that the Jinput library is not compiled to run on ARM processors:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851911/jinput-on-raspberrypi

So far so good, but this far I could not find a solution as to how I get the `.so` file compiled to run on the arm processor. I guess it is somewhat trivial for someone with the knowledge, since the file is easily decompiled and the project is open source.

But I have been stuck at this stage for the last 1½ month. Any help as to how to compile it where to find the files that are to be compiled and such, or alternatively finding an already compiled file for the raspberry pi 2 would be helpful.

Comment: I may have migrated this too quickly as there is an answer involving Raspbian packages that would have been appropriate here (as opposed to compiling and installing JNI libraries generally, which are not).  Anyway, I cannot reverse a migration and left that answer on S.O.  To find the question click the link above.