# Issues with linux and Jar files. Jar works in eclipse, but doesn't run in raspberry pi

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a .jar file made in Eclipse using JDK 11 on a raspberry pi 4. For the Raspbian OS I had to use a 64-bit version instead of a 32 bit.

I put the jar into a folder together with the native files to get it to run as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598373/in-eclipse-my-exported-executable-jar-doesnt-do-anything-lwjgl), but it doesn't seem to work.

I ran java -version in raspbian to check the version of java, and it is using 11.0.8 The project seems to run alright in Eclipse, but doesn't run on my raspberry pi. When I run the jar from the raspbian terminal, it returns the error:

`Failed to load library: /boot/arcade_test/libjinput-linux64.so: /boot/arcade_test/libjinput.64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64-bit .so on a AARCH64-bit platform)`

I don't think I'm missing the actual library. The terminal called the error a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. I used the following line to hardcode where my program should look for the library.

```
System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.librarypath", new File("/boot/arcade_test").getAbsolutePath());
```

Does anyone know what exactly is happening and how I can fix it?

Edit 1:

Here's the [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275370) to where I found the .img file for the raspbian os that I'm using

Comment: It would appear that @goldilocks answered this question a few years ago [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48154/compile-jinput-on-arm)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjinput-java libjinput-java-doc libjinput-jni`

Comment: @Dougie that just seems to lead to the same error as before

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37545912/1151724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know what exactly is happening...

The "No such file or directory" bit is probably misleading -- it is more likely the second reason, "can't load AMD 64-bit .so on a AARCH64-bit platform".  The AMD64, aka. x86-64, architecture (your normal computer running Eclipse) is not compatible with AARCH64 (the Pi).

While java byte code is portable it often depends on precompiled native libraries that it may be linked specifically to (hence "unsatisfied link" error).

> ...and how I can fix it?

You'll have to compile the code on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks, that was also my guess. When you said compiling code on the pi, what did you mean by that? Like downloading an IDE on the Pi and coding from there?

Comment: No, I mean like with a *java compiler,* which is what the IDE uses, but you don't need an IDE (or a GUI) to use it: [javac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac). You'll need to install the JDK (on Raspbian/Debian/Ubuntu etc systems `apt install openjdk-11-jdf-headless` should get you started).  Note that openjdk and the Oracle distribution (not sure they even have one for the Pi anymore) are pretty much the same at this point, I think.  There should be oodles of tutorials about using the compiler.  It is pretty simple depending on the scale of what you are up to.

Comment: This is really getting somewhere. I originally imported an external jar following [this tutorial](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse.html) to function as a library for JInput. Could I do something similar without using eclipse (for some reason, I can't install eclipse).

Comment: JInput is in the Raspbian (and probably every other linux distro) repository (`apt search jinput`).  WRT using it w/o eclipse (which methinks will never usefully run on a Pi even if you can install it, it is just too resource intensive), this is what the compiler `classpath` is for -- you really need to learn this stuff at some point, and the longer you wait the more of a hassle it will be for you.

Comment: ...This includes learning the fundamentals of java build systems, the predominant one being [maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) -- I notice the jinput github repo uses a `pom.xml` build config, == `maven`. The other one you will see a lot w/ java is `build.xml`, which is [ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) and somewhat older.  These integrate easily w/ eclipse, meaning you can use it to configure a build and then just `maven` on the Pi to automate it (since most projects involve more than just a single `javac` invocation, sourcing dependencies, etc).

Comment: Another thing to check into would be using eclipse remotely (ie., run it on your laptop with a connection to the Pi, where stuff will actually get built and exectuted).  Search online `eclipse java remote raspberry pi`, you should find lots of stuff (although as with most things you will probably find more better info if you leave the "raspberry pi" part out, or replace it with "linux", since there is probably no unique-to-pidom aspect).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured Eclipse had basically zero support on Raspberry pi, so I switched to BlueJ (comes pre-installed). I used [this](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~cs121/exercises/week1/ConfigJavaIDE.html) to import the .jar library files. I also used a System.setProperty line (similar to the one in the question post) to try to get LinuxEnvironmentPlugin and put .SOs in place, but the compiler still threw a UnsatisfiedLinkError because of failed to load library: jinput-linux64 in java.library.path. Hopefully using dependencies can save me, but at this point, I doubt my chances.

Comment: P.S. Sorry for getting back so late. Have less time to work on this project. It's possible it's some kind of incompatibility between my .so files and BlueJ causing the issue (like ARM not working with AARCH), but compiling it using java via terminal didn't reveal any other errors, just showed that the library wasn't working. The third possibility I can think of is that the directory for the SO files needs more permission to be accessed and run. (hopefully that makes sense)

Comment: P.P.S Here's the full error that I compiling it via BlueJ:                                                                                                                                                          Loading: net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin
Failed to load library: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/jni, /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf, /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
net.java.games.input.LinuxEnvironmentPlugin is not supported